# Unable to add elastislide js file in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, jquery, slider

I am trying to add elastislide,
for that, I added this code in phtml file

```
<div class="brand_block">
 <ul id="carousel_<?php echo $chunk2->getId(); ?>" class="elastislide-list"> 
    <?php   
     print($_category->getData('brand_block'));?>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','js/jquery.elastislide','js/modernizr.custom.17475'],
    function (jQuery) { 
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery('#carousel_<?php echo $chunk2->getId(); ?>').elastislide(); 
        });
    });

</script>
```

I've added modernizr.custom.17475.js and jquery.elastislide.js in `/app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/web/js` folder

I am getting these errors in console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>       at jquery.elastislide.js:820 (anonymous) @ jquery.elastislide.js:820 (index):296 Uncaught TypeError:
>   jQuery(...).elastislide is not a function

Comment: try replacing `jQuery` with `$` in your script code

Comment: still getting same errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `js/jquery.elastislide` not recognizing jquery means you have not assigned `shim` that will create your js dependency to jquery in `requirejs-config.js`

Your code should look like in `requirejs-config.js` :

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'elastislide': 'js/jquery.elastislide'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        'js/jquery.elastislide': ['jquery']
    }
};
```

You javascript function should look like this.

```
<script>
require([
    "jquery",
    "elastislide",
    "js/modernizr.custom.17475",
    "domReady!"
], function($){
    $('#carousel_<?php echo $chunk2->getId(); ?>').elastislide();
});
</script>
```

If you running production mode make sure deploy static content and clear cache.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

If you are in development environment you can just clear cache and changes will update.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Note you should also assign `js/modernizr.custom.17475` in `requirejs-config.js` if its depends on jquery.

Comment: thank you but still getting same errors

Comment: See i have updated answer

Comment: Do I have to put  requirejs-config.js in app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web ?

Comment: You can put `requirejs-config.js` in `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme`

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked